# Android google maps API - unfocus marker listener

Tags: android, android-maps

I'd like to add an unfocus listener on the markers of my map, but it doesn't seem to exists. What would be the best way to do that?

I do understand that there is no unfocus listener function, sorry for the unclear explanation. When I click on a marker I show a linearLayout on the bottom of the screen and modify a textview. What I want to do is hide this linearLayout when the user clicks somewhere else on the map.

I don't want to use InfoWindow.

Comment: @user1701566 an edit has been made to my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may achieve that by:

- remembering currently focused `Marker` in `onMarkerClick` or `getInfoWindow`
- clearing currently focused `Marker` in `onMapClick` and also after other events like `setVisible` or `remove` called on focused `Marker` (if you use them in your code)

Answer (score 2):

There is no UNFOCUS in markers because there is no need. When you click anywhere else on the map it will automatically be unfocused. 
EDIT : 
You can use `onMapClickListner` to get the click on the map. This way the marker will automatically unfocused and you can handled that event.